# unable to access link

Tags: php, curl

I have a small problem. I am trying to submit a form to
http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/Inquiry.aspx

but it cannot be directly navigate even in browser(i really don't have a clue why?)
to go to above link it is mandatory to click "Parcel enquiry" on 
http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/MainMenu.aspx?c=32

so i want to click and follow the "parcel enquiry" link using a php script.
if i directly access the former link using cURL i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

please guide me on how to click and follow the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result using PHP you will need to have the Javascript function that is called on clicking 'Parcel Inquiry' in your PHP script, to mimic the result:

HTML for the link in your PHP script:

```
<a id="ctl00_Main_lnkParcelInquiry" style="color:Blue;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lnkParcelInquiry','')">Parcel Inquiry</a>
```

JS to define the __doPostBack function and form in your PHP script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>
<script src="/PropertyTax/Grundy/WebResource.axd?d=k82Y5NDDJDDbxvQs15CYbKKGrXzg8maOqY0bqltbogQI3NDmBuf75gWfcLjILBbAmbWOYgfVPqLiO6Kf2KileNBCke01&amp;t=634622168376055000" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And so you will also need that form, `<form name="aspnetForm" action="http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/Inquiry.aspx">`, to exist in your script.

It's just a matter of doing it the same way; so copy the code and the functions and you should get the same results.